# Android admob can't see

Tags: android, admob

Admob code can't see on device.

I followed the instructions here: http://www.admob.com/docs/AdMob_Android_SDK_Instructions.pdf

everything ok, but the 6. not clear for me

> "
>   Step 6
>
> When integrating AdMob ads into your application it is
>   recommended to use test mode. In test mode test, ads are always
>   returned. Test mode is enabled on a per-device basis. To enable test
>   mode for a device, first request an ad, then look in LogCat for a line
>   like the following: To get test ads on the emulator use
>   AdManager.setTestDevices... Once you have the device ID you can enable
>   test mode by calling AdManager.setTestDevices:

```
AdManager.setTestDevices( new String[] { AdManager.TEST_EMULATOR, //    Android emulator 
"E83D20734F72FB3108F104ABC0FFC738", // My T-Mobile G1 Test Phone 
} ); }
```

"

What is that long number on the code? How do I get that number?

In the oncreate method I put this code:

```
AdManager.setTestDevices(new String[] { AdManager.TEST_EMULATOR } );
```

(into the help activity, not into the main activity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you must start the app on the real device to get a device id

Answer (score 2):

Open the LogCat window, start app in the emulator. Then the number appear in that window

Answer (score 0):

Step 6 is only to get the ads to show up in the emulator.  They should still show up on the phone if you have done the other steps correctly.

I haven't ever done step six but it looks like you need to get your device id using the following function, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDeviceId()

Be sure to remove this when you want to publish though, if it's still in there you wont be making any money.

Hope that helps

Comment: how i can use real ads? not the test ads?

Comment: I believe you just have to comment out the stuff you added from step 6 before you publish your app.  The test ads are for you to test it out without incurring some unauthorized activity on your account.

Answer (score 0):

You must search for something like

> 11-15 22:35:59.578: INFO/AdMobSDK(9775): To get test ads on this device use AdManager.setTestDevices( new String[] { "A32123456AA234567ABB12AA34BB3421234" } )

in the logcat. It's easier if you use the filter AdMobSDK